# C++ project type in repository

Tags: bitbucket

I found I have C++ project in my Bitbucket project list with dark blue C++ icon.

[image]

All my projects are C++. How to give them such type?

Usually when I create project from web page it not gives option to select project type. Why? How to get it?

What gives C++ option in project type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your repository's **settings page**:

[image]

Select a language in the **language dropdown** where it says *Select language*:

[image]

Click *Save repository details* after.